# signalR message structure flags clarification?

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I've read [**here**](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/887) about the structure of signalR's response message :

for example

- For `PersistentConnection`

  `{"C":"B,2CE|K,C|L,2|M,0|I,0|J,0","M":["foo"]}`

Where

```
Persistent Response:
C - cursor
M - Messages
T - Timeout (only if true) value is 1
D - Disconnect (only if true) value is 1
R - All Groups (Client groups should be reset to match this list exactly)
G - Groups added
g - Groups removed
```

<kbd>Question #1</kbd>

What's wrong with sending **only** the message part ? why do i need all the "C" information ? The client only needs the message. A message number #N is **not** dependent with message number #N-1 (AFAIK)  -- so I dont see the reason for this "C" section. ( and I assume Im wrong by missing something here).

<kbd>Question #2</kbd>

Even so , how can I understand what the tokens means ? I didn't see in the manual the "K,L,I,J,2CE" tokens.

Where / How can I understand what they are saying ? What if I don't want the server to send that info but only the message ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open Source has an often over looked feature.  You can simply download the source and take a look around.  By simply searching in the source for the string "R" I was able to find some of the information you are looking for.

<kbd>Answer #2:</kbd>
These shorthand property names directly map to the JsonSerialization of objects in SignalR.
HubResponse

- S - State
- R - Result
- I - Id
- E - Error
- T - StackTrace

PersistantResponse

- L - LongPollDelay
- D - Disconnect
- T - TimedOut
- G - GroupsToken

Some of the others are not found in the current code base, and since the issue your referring to is 7 months old I would guess they have been refactored out.

<kbd>Answer #1:</kbd>
The metadata is important to how SignalR operates.  The double edged sword of frameworks is that we offload the domain or what it solves to the framework and its creators, and we implicitly agree to let them be the domain expert.  Sometimes that makes it a bit of a black box to use, if you want to see what each of these properties are actually used for download the source and follow the code.  If for some performance reason you feel the need to trim out some of the code around what you determine to be extraneous fork the code and give it a shot.